# calling functions and passing information between views

Tags: iphone, delegates, tableview, addchild

**Thanks in advance for your help!**

In the main ViewController.m of my project I am adding a customized tableView like so:

```
messageController = [[MyMessagesController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
[self addChildViewController:messageController];
[self.view addSubview:messageController.view];
```

Then, in the MyMessagesController.m section tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: I'd like to write code that would take effect in the ViewController.m where it was created and added as a childViewController.

How can I access the functions of the ViewController.m from MyMessagesController.m?

Can I make it a delegate somehow so I could call [delegate functionName];?
Could I pass information back to the ViewController.m? About which of the rows in table was selected by sending through an NSString or NSArray or anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured out, here's how you turn one viewController into a delegate for another:

In the .h of the parent controller -

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <NameOfDelegate> {
```

In the .m of the parent controller, once you create the new view -

```
newViewController.delegate = self;
```

and also:

```
- (void)functionToCall:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Function Called!!!");
}
```

In the .h of the newViewController you're adding -

```
@protocol NameOfDelegate;

@interface newViewController : UIViewController/OR/TableViewController {
    id <NameOfDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) id <NameOfDelegate> delegate;

@end

@protocol NameOfDelegate
- (void)functionToCall:(id)sender;
@end
```

in the .m of the newViewController -

```
@implementation newViewController

@synthesize delegate;
```

and when you're ready to call the function in your delegate -

```
[delegate functionToCall:self];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use a delegate, if you are unsure how best to accomplish this, [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html) is a good reference from Apple about delegate programming

Comment: Yes - that is what I am looking for... how do I create this view to be a delegate for the original view so that I can interact with it?

Comment: You declare a delegate protocol that has the methods you need, parameters and all, declare your child VC to have a delegate that adheres to that protocol, and make sure your parent VC implements that protocol, and then set the delegate like you would for any other object that has a delegate.  All of this is laid out in the link I provided in the answer